# Issue with match dates inaccurate - Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Issue with match dates inaccurate

Hello, got issues index match formulas with the dates of two groups where is shown the last date of given ref that should be the same in the other side,
i appreciate your help please, i'm driving nuts here lol, can't find the way to make it work

There are two sections, MISSIONS & CURRENCY in tab 403
I'm looking to match the last dates of the mission and its currencies, shown in the sync_MISREP-23 tab

The pilot 403 made a mission AHC on 22 Jul 2023 and I'm need to show the same dates of its currencies witch should be the same

Here's the test sheet
I appreciate your help and thanks in advance

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ewWYMcXRsB88o99X-i9NA8BohU1UMbVh2zeH11Aiuow/edit#gid=1353675438

On table (tab) 403 I have this formula to retrieve the last date performed(column AM) on the second table "currencies" based on the currency type(column AA) but always gave me 5 rows below from the dataset "sync_MISREP-23"

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As you see in 403 tab, the last mission was on 22 JUL 2023 therefore, the last currency(right section), should be the same but instead, picks up the 5 rows bellows "6 JAN 2023 (look in sync_MISREP-23 TAB)" and this is basically happening with everything.